# Send OSC Messages from Mobmuplat to Python

Tags: python, mobile, send, osc, puredata

I have MobMuPlat running on my phone, I can send messages to PureData, and then PureData receives the data and sends that to Python.
Is it possible to avoid PureData section? How can I read messages from MobMuPlat on Python ?

Thank you

I amb thinking about using python-osc or socket, but nothing works fine.

Comment: what do you mean with "nothing works fine"? show us your code!